# Retorno Json do php para jquery ui

Tags: php, ajax, json

Tenho um código em php que faz um retorno de dados em JSON.
Quando tem somente um valor retorna como deveria:

> ["ezekielEBurt@dayrep.com"]

Quando é encontrado mais de um valor retorna da seguinte forma:

> [, "cairo@mail.com", "ezekielEBurt@dayrep.com", ,].

Como faço para que retorne desta forma?:

> ["cairo@mail.com", "ezekielEBurt@dayrep.com"]

Segue abaixo o script PHP:

```
<?php
$lik = mysql_connect("localhost",'root','root');
$link = mysql_select_db('projeto4',$lik);

$search = $_GET['term'];
$qr = "SELECT nome,email FROM usuarios WHERE nome LIKE '%$search%' ORDER BY nome ASC";
$ex = mysql_query($qr) or die (mysql_error());

$resJson = '[';
$first = true;

while($res = mysql_fetch_array($ex)):
    if(!$first):
        $resJson .= ', ';
    else:
        $first = false;
    endif;
    $resJson .= json_encode($res['email']);
endwhile;

$resJson .= ']';

echo $resJson;
```

Answer (score 1):

Transforme a sua string `$resJson` em um array assim `$resJson = array();`

Depois você vai apenas incrementar o array com os valores assim:

```
array_push($resJson, $res['email']);
```

No final você usa o  `json_encode($resJson);`

Exemplo no [ideone](http://ideone.com/LfK7l9)

Answer (score 1):

O problema é que em seu bando nem todos os registro devem ter email assim lhe gerando conteúdos com valor `vazio`.
Para revolver este problema você pode fazer assim :

```
$resJson = '[';
$first = true;

while($res = mysql_fetch_array($ex)):
    if(!empty($res['email'])){    // condição a mais
        if(!$first):
            $resJson .= ', ';
        else:
            $first = false;
        endif;
        $resJson .= json_encode($res['email']);
    }
endwhile;

$resJson .= ']';
```

Usando o corigo que ja tem apenas adicionando mais uma condição.

Ou fazer assim :

```
$resJson = array();
while($res = mysql_fetch_array($ex)):
    if(!empty($res['email'])){
        $resJson[] = $res['email'];
    }
endwhile;

echo json_encode($resJson);
```

Ou ainda assim :

```
$resJson = array();
while($res = mysql_fetch_array($ex)):
    $resJson[] = $res['email'];
endwhile;

$resJson = array_filter($resJson, function($item){
    return !empty($item);
});

echo json_encode($resJson);
```

Todos eles tem o intuito de remover os valores `vazios`.